# How to replicate fence svg as a gradient

Tags: css, gradient

svg fence x

```
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
```

To do this, what is needed here is to create the x pattern shape made up of 16 tiny **1px** squares and a bigger one **2px** in the middle.

[image]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" ><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>
```

Blown up in size it looks like this.

The gradient would be made of the darker shaded square spots.

[image]

Here is the svg Fence pattern: I want to make using a gradient replicating the svg.

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>');
}
```

Comment: Please include any code you have already. Tried. I’m not sure what the significance of its being originally an svg is. Does it make straight line linear gradients unacceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/cruboqyt/

```
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

Gradient is the **1st** code, svg is the **2nd** code.

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.test1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    );
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.test2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div class="test1"></div>
<hr>
<div class="test2"></div>
```